# Replace a string inside a dictionary that's inside a list of dictionaries (Tweets from Twitter)

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop, twitter

I have a list of tweets I collected from the Twitter API.

Each tweet in the list is in the form of a dictionary.

**I want to change all of the strings 'en-gb' within this file to 'en'.**

Here is a list of two of the tweets:

```
twitter_tweets =  
[{'created_at': 'Wed Oct 18 22:20:30 +0000 2017', 'id': 920776631102214144, 'user': {'id': 119116331, 'statuses_count': 32796, 'verified': False, 'lang': 'en-'}, 'retweet_count': 0, 'favorite_count': 0}
{'created_at': 'Wed Oct 17 12:20:36 +0000 2017', 'id': 920776631106514144, 'user': {'id': 119159331, 'statuses_count': 32796, 'verified': False, 'lang': 'en-gb'}, 'retweet_count': 1, 'favorite_count': 2}]
```

Note the location of the "en-gb" string:

While each tweet is a dictionary, the key 'user' has a secondary dictionary as its value. One of the keys inside that secondary dictionary is 'lang' (Language) and, its value is sometimes 'en-gb' ("British English").

I want to change all of the values 'en-gb' to 'en'.

I tried this, but to no avail:

```
for item in enumerate(twitter_tweets):
    for item == 'en-gb':
        item = 'en'
```

Comment: Try printing `item`. You'll notice that `enumerate` is not the right tool for the job :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace them by iterating through the list

```
for d in twitter_cumulative_datascience_tweets:
    if d['user']['lang'] == 'en-gb':
        d['user']['lang'] = 'en'
```

Comment: Yes, that did it. Thank you!

Comment: Yep, I'm just waiting for the time limit to pass -- I guess I have to wait about 10 minutes after the question is asked to mark your response as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
tweets = [{'created_at': 'Wed Oct 18 22:20:30 +0000 2017', 'id': 920776631102214144, 'user': {'id': 119116331, 'statuses_count': 32796, 'verified': False, 'lang': 'en-'}, 'retweet_count': 0, 'favorite_count': 0}, {'created_at': 'Wed Oct 17 12:20:36 +0000 2017', 'id': 920776631106514144, 'user': {'id': 119159331, 'statuses_count': 32796, 'verified': False, 'lang': 'en-gb'}, 'retweet_count': 1, 'favorite_count': 2}]
final_tweets = [{"created_at":i["created_at"], "id":i["id"], "user":{a:"en" if b == "en-gb" else b for a, b in i["user"].items()}} for i in tweets]
```

Output:

```
[{'created_at': 'Wed Oct 18 22:20:30 +0000 2017', 'id': 920776631102214144, 'user': {'lang': 'en-', 'statuses_count': 32796, 'verified': False, 'id': 119116331}}, {'created_at': 'Wed Oct 17 12:20:36 +0000 2017', 'id': 920776631106514144, 'user': {'lang': 'en', 'statuses_count': 32796, 'verified': False, 'id': 119159331}}]
```